# jQuery animate slide down on click but not back up on click

Tags: jquery, html, animation, click, slide

I've messed around with this teeny little detail for hours now and I've finally given up even though I'm sure the solution is really, really simple.

I have a panel called ".address" in a div with overflow:hidden so it isn't shown before the function is activated. When clicking on the button ".click" I want the address div to slide down from the hidden area and into visible view. So far this works, but I cannot figure out why it won't slide back up on the second click.

```
    $(".click").click(function(){
        $(".address").animate({top:"0"},{duration:200});
            }, function() {
        $(".address").animate({top:"-55px"},{duration:200});
    });
```

Can anyone explain to me the solution to this? It's probably an obvious solution but I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: visit this url:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138728/how-to-make-two-functions-react-on-a-click?answertab=oldest#tab-top

theres a good explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) to cycle between two (or more) functions (rather than [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) which is just using your first function), like this:

```
$(".click").toggle(function(){
    $(".address").animate({top:"0"},{duration:200});
}, function() {
    $(".address").animate({top:"-55px"},{duration:200});
});
```

Comment: I'd throw a stop() in there before each animate() so extra clicks don't bounce the container open and shut a bunch of times.

Comment: @Surreal - It's such a short duration, that it would be tough to create much of a backlog of animations. Otherwise `.stop()` is a good idea.

Comment: Heh, I didn't even think about the duration.  I'm really just a stickler about bouncy animations.  :)

Comment: Much appreciated, this did it. Typical really, it was also the first thing that came to mind as I woke up this morning. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun approach.

```
$(".click").click(function() {
    var idx = 0;
    return function() {
        $(".address").animate({top: (idx = ++idx % 2) ? 0 : -55}, {duration: 200});
    };
}());
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jSsgM/1/

[@Nick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221085/jquery-animate-slide-down-on-click-but-not-back-up-on-click/4221090#4221090) is cleaner and more sensible, and should be used especially if you're going to be doing anything more complex.