# How to make two functions react on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slide

I am new to JS.

Right now I managed to make a text appear and a div slide to the right when I click on a div.

The problem is: How can I manage to do this in reverse? (with the same animation)

I tried the if/else statement but I cant get it done. Hope some of you can help me.

**Here is my Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#profile').click(function() {
            $('#profile-info').fadeIn("").addClass('animated fadeInDown');
            $('#profile').animate({left:'200px'}, 800,'swing');
        });
    });
```

**Here is my HTML code**

```
<section>
<div id="profile">
    </div>
        <div id="profile-photo">
        </div>
            <div id="profile-info">
                <p>Hello, I'm</p> 
                    <p>Rick James</p>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: can u make a fiddle with your code???     --> jsfiddle.net

Comment: Where is the relevant css mentioned in code...?

Comment: Yes, either make a jsFiddle or atleast provide the markup of the animated and fadeInDown CSS classes?

Comment: By "in reverse" do you mean by clicking on the same button? Or do you mean after a certain period of time in the .animate call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I'm using

```
if ( $( "#profile-info" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) { 
   //do this
} else {
   //do this
}
```

So basically if it is hidden it will do the code, the if not, the other desired code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#profile').click(function() {
           if ( $( "#profile-info" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $('#profile-info').fadeIn("").addClass('animated fadeInDown');
            $('#profile').animate({left:'200px'}, 800,'swing');
           } else {
            $('#profile-info').fadeOut("").removeClass('animated fadeInDown');
            $('#profile').animate({left:'200px'}, 800,'swing');
           }
        });
    });
```

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/509/

**UPDATED:**

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#profile').click(function() {
           if ( $( "#profile-info" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $('#profile-info').fadeIn("").addClass('animated fadeInDown');
            $('#profile-info').animate({left:'0px',opacity:1}, 800,'swing');

           } else {
            $('#profile-info').animate({left:'200px',opacity:0}, 800,'swing');
            $('#profile-info').fadeOut("").removeClass('animated fadeInDown');

         }
      });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
        <div id="profile">
            test
        </div>

        <div id="profile-photo">
        </div>

        <div id="profile-info">
            <p>Hello, I'm</p> 
            <p>Rick James</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#profile-info {
    display: none;
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/512/

Comment: this works perfect! thanks!! +1
only how can i manage to make #profile-info fade out with a animation instead of the simply fadeOut function

Comment: thanks... and if you want to add animation to it, you could just change the jquery from `fadeOut` to something like `slideUp`. DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/510/

Comment: Or you could set the div to `position:relative;` and use animation with jquery: see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/511/

Comment: There is one more thing you can do to make it a little nice when it fades in: You can animate the opacity so it does everything at once: http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/512/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#profile').click(function() {
        if($(this).css('left') !== '200px'){
        $('#profile-info').fadeIn("").addClass('animated fadeInDown');
        $('#profile').animate({left:'200px'}, 800,'swing');
       } else {
             $('#profile-info').fadeIn("").removeClass('animated fadeInDown');
        $('#profile').animate({left:'0px'}, 800,'swing'); 
       } 
    });
});
```

Comment: this works fine! only the text just will be out in an instant instead of fading out. but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeToggle(options)` and `toggleClass()` from jQuery for this.